# Move Spotlight dialog in Yosemite

Tags: macos, spotlight

Don't hate me but I love using Finder's spotlight feature.

In Yosemite they changed Spotlight (I like the changes) but they moved the spotlight dialog position to the center of the screen. I want to move it back to the upper right side of my screen (where it used to live).
Also is there a way to darken the background of spotlight results.
Spotlight gets lost among the mass of windows I have open.

Thanks in advance!
C

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think anyone has discovered a way to move it back other than to downgrade your OS. I do not understand your second question!

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
The  second question regards changing the background color of spotlight results.

I tend to have too many windows open. The spotlight results window is not distinct enough for me. It gets lost among the sea of windows I have open.

Comment: Hi Craig, yet again, I don't think it is possible. Sorry! Please vote my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to move the Spotlight dialog as far as I know, but enabling dark mode (System Preferences > General > "Use dark menu bar and Dock") will switch the dialog to a dark background.